# jQuery File Upload - finishing uploads

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I have really simple jQuery File Upload application. With default layout.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    autoUpload: true,
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
});
```

The .done() is running fine, but the file doesnt dissapered (doesnt change the template to the `template-download` template).
[image]

No matter how many files I upload that happening. The global progress bar (between the buttons [+ Add files] and list of files) dissapering, but progress bar stay for each files.

Response as json from server:

```
{"files":[{"name":"uploads\/images\/2015\/08\/4638188810_2a2dc4772b-f8acf8a5ab523d285b0475e73bea21b9203e5058
.jpeg"}]}
```

What's wrong?

**UPDATE**

I just fixed the problem.
To listening the done() event you cannot add the function to the main fileupload() init function. Use the event listener ;)

Solution:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    autoUpload: true
});

$('#fileupload')
    .bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    })
;
```

Comment: And what do you want?

Comment: To change the `template-upload` theme used while upload to the `template-download` where user will be able to get a link for the image :)
That should happen automatically - as on demo page.